# Reading from an oven humidity sensor

Tags: sensors

I have been trying to solve the problem of humidity sensors in a harsh environment (BBQ/Pizza Oven) and I came across this:
[enter link description here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/KitchenAid-KMCS3022GSS-Microwave-Humidity-Gas-Steam-Temp-Sensor-FAST-FREE-SHIPP/202626961133?_trkparms=aid%3D1110001%26algo%3DSPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D20160323102634%26meid%3Db39b2c9929b44a659853f0f2f644e4d5%26pid%3D100623%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D121076623235%26itm%3D202626961133%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675&_trksid=p2047675.c100623.m-1)

But I don't see any documentation on how to connect such a sensor to an arduino.

Are there any examples of how to integrate this?

Comment: I doubt you'll find a documentation, because it is a spare part for a microwave oven. I also think, it can not be used in hot environment. The air in an microwave oven is cold compared to a pizza oven ;-). The isolation of the inner wires could melt away and you have a short circuit. I don't know if the sensor itself (without the wires)  is made for hot environments. I haven't found any specification too. As I have written, its a spare part and used to replace defect ones in a microwave oven. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akQ8zCFk_VY .

Comment: The title also say is a "Microwave Humidity Gas Steam Temp Sensor". I would interpret that, as if it can measure the temperature of the humidity gas (i.e the vaporized water).  But perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: In general, it's always better to try something first - then ask here. I think what you are asking for is difficult as humidity detection at pizza / baking temperatures 400+ F are likely not kind to COTS humidity sensors. My guess, humidity control is empirically arrived at using the ambient room temperature & humidity and the oven's current temperature plus the amount of water squirted into the oven plus the water content of the food. If you want, you could start looking for academic papers like [this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.554.8436&rep=rep1&type=pdf).